# Visual Studio C++ cannot find OpenCV-Contrib modules

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, cmake, include

I am trying to use OpenCV [multi-target tracker](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/d07/tutorial_multitracker.html), but cannot include the header files. I have built OpenCV with extra modules by providing the path to `opencv_contrib-4.2.0\modules` in **OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH** in **CMake GUI**. However, I cannot include the trackers in the project:

---

#### code:

```c
#include <opencv2/tracking.hpp>
```

#### error:

> cannot open source file "opencv2/tracking.hpp"

---

#### code:

```c
#include "samples_utility.hpp"
```

#### error:

> Cannot open include file: 'samples_utility.hpp': No such file or directory

---

What should I do to add all the modules of **OpenCV-contrib** to the default OpenCV directory?

Comment: Yes, **tracking.hpp** is in `opencv4.2.0\include\opencv2` and **samples_utility.hpp** is in `opencv4.2.0\samples\tracking`

Comment: Is it the only header file that the compiler can not find?

Comment: No, it can't find any header files from OpenCV-contrib

Comment: I'm afraid non the contrib modules aren't built correctly (check the lib and dll files). Did Opencv.Sln build all libraries without any error?

Comment: Yes **Opencv.Sln** built all libraries without any error (all build successfully). Is it necessary to build with **contrib ** modules or is it enough to just add them to include directory in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes you must build the contrib and opencv itself at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to add all the modules. Only the modules you need, and in this case the tracking module. You will need to add the corresponding folder to the include directory and the code should compile properly.(your folder might be in different location but the relative path should be the same)

> {location_of_opencv_contrib}\modules\tracking\include
>
> {location_of_opencv_contrib}\modules\tracking\samples

For visual studio, you can add the folder path above to Project Properties-> VC++ Directories -> Include Directories

If you are building using gcc, add -I option followed by the directory of the folder mentioned.

Comment: I did as you said but now getting other errors all saying `C3646 'CV_OVERRIDE': unknown override specifier`. The version of **OpenCV-contrib** is the same as *OpenCV**. both are 4.2

Comment: then you need to use your version of opencv-contrib. The error occurs because of  version mismatch between the main opencv and opencv-contrib